# Camel ActiveMQ + Spring boot not reading spring activemq configurations

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying a very simple route with Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE + Camel (Spring Boot Starter) + ActiveMQ, which is to read from a particular queue and then log it. However, it looks like it is not picking up my spring.activemq configuration for URL as I see in the log it is trying to connect to a different url and it continues to connect it and the my spring boot app never starts. The questions are based on my configuration that I am providing below how can I do the below:

1. Fix the configuration to allow spring's activemq configuration
2. Configure maxReconnectAttempts so that it does not try to connect forever if the URL is not reachable, which could be possible if the ActiveMQ instance goes down

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I did search relevant questions on stackoverflow but none gave me a solution to the issue I am facing

Error I am seeing on the console and this continues to like 60-70 attempts and counting. As you can see the broker URL that camel is picking up is some default URL that probably spring has configured by default

```
Failed to connect to [tcp://localhost:61616] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
```

Here are my current configurations / code:

pom.xml - relevant portion

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Cloud is part of the project where I am configuring camel routes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- I have this as the same project works as a web app as well 
    and therefore I do not need the 
    camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true configuration to be set
    which is as per camel's spring boot documentation-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Camel - start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Camel - end -->

</dependencies>
```

application.yml ([Spring Boot ActiveMQProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/activemq/ActiveMQProperties.java))

```
spring:
  activemq:
    brokerUrl: tcp://my.company.host:[port] //This port is up and running
    user: user
    password: password
```

Camel Route in JAVA

```
package com.mycamel.route;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SampleAmqCamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("activemq:some.queue").to("log:com.mycamel.route?level=INFO&groupSize=10");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should add the `spring-boot-starter-activemq` dependency to your pom.xml. Then you can use its AutoConfiguration capabilities which will create a `ConnectionFactory` based on the properties you have specified in your application.yml.

After that you have to configure Camel's `ActiveMQComponent` too. If you would like to reuse the `ConnectionFactory` (which created by the autoconfig) then it can be achievable with the following:

```
@Configuration
public class ActiveMQComponentConfig {

    @Bean(name = "activemq")
    public ActiveMQComponent createComponent(ConnectionFactory factory) {
        ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
        activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(factory);
        return activeMQComponent;
    }
}
```

You can find more information in [Camel's ActiveMQ documentation](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html).

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Adding the "activemq" bean did the trick. I did add the spring-boot-starter-activemq dependency and that did not work as well. The combination of both did the trick actually.