# application.yaml spring.activemq.broker-url not set

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, yaml, activemq-classic

I'm trying to set my spring app to listen to a JMS queue.
I try to set the broker-url in my application.yml but it always seems to default back to "localhost:61616".
The application.yml file is loaded from another application, but I don't think that matters since other properties in the file are read (the name of the queues for example)

Here is the message I get :

```
o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport;Failed to connect to [tcp://localhost:61616] after: 40 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
```

**What I tried**

I've tried following the answer to this question : [Camel ActiveMQ + Spring boot not reading spring activemq configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831782/camel-activemq-spring-boot-not-reading-spring-activemq-configurations)
Which is my exact issue

But when I try adding the dependency and creating that class I get this error :

```
Parameter 0 of method createComponent in xxx.xxxxx.xxxx.configuration.ActiveMQComponentConfig required a bean of type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' that could not be found.
```

I'm quite new to Spring boot / ActiveMQ and don't really know what to do about this.

Here's the relevant part of my pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And my application.yml :

```
spring:
  aop:
    proxy-target-class: true
  cache:
    ehcache:
      config: classpath:ehcache.xml
  activemq:
    broker-url: tcp://foo:12345
    pool:
      enabled: true
      max-connections: 5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I already spent a fair amount of time on this and not making any progress

Comment: There is a little camel activemq example at: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-spring-boot-activemq which may help

Comment: For now I've bypassed this by creating my own config for activemq instead of relying on Spring boot's config. Seems to work so far but it's not optimal, so I'll check that example tomorrow, thanks !

Comment: Can you tell how you have done it on your own?

Comment: @Arun I'll make an answer with it

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing to get it to work again. I still don't know why Spring's autoconfig stopped working but that solved it

```java
@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {

    @Value("${spring.activemq.broker-url}")
    String BROKER_URL;
    @Value("${spring.activemq.user}")
    String BROKER_USERNAME;
    @Value("${spring.activemq.password}")
    String BROKER_PASSWORD;

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(BROKER_URL);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(BROKER_USERNAME);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(BROKER_PASSWORD);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
        return factory;
    }
}
```